# ¿ Por qué no muestra nada en el div?

Tags: ajax, mvc, razor

En `PRUEBA1.cshtml`le paso el nombre de un libro con `ajax`al controlador de `PRUEBA2`, este al recibir el nombre, con una `función buscarLibros(String nombre)` devuelve una lista y la muestra en la`view PRUEBA2`. Lo que yo estoy intentando hacer es que lo que se ve en la `view PRUEBA2` me aparezca en un `<div>` que tengo en `PRUEBA1.cshtml`, pero no me esta funcionando, no muestra nada en el `<div>`.

Cuando hago el debug, el nombre llega perfecto al `controlador` y la `función buscarLibros(String nombre)`me esta funcionando bien, pero como dije antes, no muestra nada en el `<div>`.

```
Aca los controladores
```

```html
 public ActionResult PRUEBA1()
 {
     return View();       
 }
```

```html
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PRUEBA2(String data)
        {     
            LibroService ls = new LibroService();
            List<Libro> lista = new List<Libro>();
            lista = ls.buscarLibros(data);
            return View(lista);          
        }
```

```
Aca PRUEBA1.cshtml
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nombreLibro" />
<button type="button" onclick="filtrar();">Buscar</button>
<div id="IdDeAlgunDivDondeColocarasEsaVista"></div>
```

```
Aca ajax
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    function filtrar() {

        var uri = '@Url.Action("PRUEBA2", "Usser")';
        
        if ($("#nombreLibro").val().length <= 0) {
            alert("el campo esta vacio!");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,  
                data: { data: $("#nombreLibro").val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (respuestaDelServidor) {
                    $("#IdDeAlgunDivDondeColocarasEsaVista").html(respuestaDelServidor);
                }
            });
        }

    }

</script>
```

```
Aca PRUEBA2.cshtml
```

```html
@using Librery_MVC.Models;
@using Librery_MVC.Services;

<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-primary mt-5 table-bordered" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>        
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Autor</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>                   
                    <th>Precio</th>                  
                    <th>Accion</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (Libro item in Model)
                {

                    autor = sa.getAutor(item.IdAutor);
                    editorial = es.GetEditorial(item.IdEditorial);
                    category = cs.getCategoria(item.IdCategoria);

                    <tr>
                        <th><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>

                        <th>@item.IdLibro</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">@item.Nombre</th>
                        <th>@autor.Nombre</th>
                        <th>@category.Nombre</th>
                        <th>@item.Precio</th>
                        <th>
                            <input type="hidden" name="inputText" id="inputText" value="@item.IdLibro" />
                            @Html.ActionLink("Mostrar", "MostrarLibro", "Usser", new { idLibro = item.IdLibro }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                            <button onclick="createTable('@item.IdLibro', '@item.Nombre');" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnAgregar">Seleccionar</button>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Aca lo que marca la Network

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO! borre la linea `dataType: 'json',`. Quedando el codigo ajax de la siguiente forma:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    function filtrar() {

        var uri = '@Url.Action("PRUEBA2", "Usser")';
        
        if ($("#nombreLibro").val().length <= 0) {
            alert("el campo esta vacio!");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,  
                data: { data: $("#nombreLibro").val() },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (respuestaDelServidor) {   
                    $("#IdDeAlgunDivDondeColocarasEsaVista").html(respuestaDelServidor);
                }
            });
        }

    }

</script>
```